# Equinox Weaving doesn't work in Virgo tomcat

Tags: equinox, eclipse-virgo, compile-time-weaving

I'm using equinox weaving to do aspect across bundles in Virgo tomcat, I followed the [weaving sample](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php). It worked fine in eclipse target platform. But when I deployed into virgo, it didn't work.

I modified  config.ini like below

```
……
osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj@2\:start,org.aspectj.weaver@2\:start,org.aspectj.runtime@2\:start
aj.weaving.verbose=true
org.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true
org.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true
……
```

No exception occrred when starting Virgo, and bundles' state were correct

```
id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521
                    Fragments=1, 34
1       RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000
                    Master=0
2       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj_1.0.300.I20130319-1000
3       ACTIVE      org.aspectj.weaver_1.7.3.20130613144500-a
4       ACTIVE      org.aspectj.runtime_1.7.3.20130613144500-a
```

I found some difference in consoles. When starting in eclipse target platform, next tow statements displayed in consoles

```
[org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook] info adding AspectJ hooks ...
[org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj] info Starting AspectJ weaving service ...
```

But when starting in Virgo, just the second one displayed. I considered maybe the hook didn't start correctly, but i'm not sure. Anyone can help me?